# Undesirable Flow/TypeScript types being generated from OpenAPI's `oneOf` keyword. Is there another OpenAPI schema that would have better results?

Tags: typescript, openapi, flowtype

We have the following OpenAPI schema:

```js
{
    "openapi": "3.0.1",
    "paths": {
        "/v1/tool/breadcrumbs/{hierarchyId}/{categoryId}": {
            "get": {
                "tags": [
                    "V1-tool"
                ],
                "summary": "Get Breadcrumbs details",
                "operationId": "getBreadcrumbs",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "hierarchyId",
                        "in": "path",
                        "required": true,
                        "schema": {
                            "minimum": 1,
                            "type": "integer",
                            "format": "int32"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "categoryId",
                        "in": "path",
                        "required": true,
                        "schema": {
                            "minimum": 1,
                            "type": "integer",
                            "format": "int32"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "default response",
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "items": {
                                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Kitten"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "security": [
                    {
                        "Auth": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "/v1/tool/hierarchies": {
            "get": {
                "tags": [
                    "V1-tool"
                ],
                "summary": "Get all available hierarchies ",
                "operationId": "getAllHierarchies",
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "default response",
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "items": {
                                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/HierarchyResponse"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "security": [
                    {
                        "Auth": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "/v1/tool/search/{hierarchyId}/{searchTerm}": {
            "get": {
                "tags": [
                    "V1-tool"
                ],
                "summary": "Free text search categories for a given hierarchy",
                "operationId": "searchBy",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "hierarchyId",
                        "in": "path",
                        "required": true,
                        "schema": {
                            "minimum": 1,
                            "type": "integer",
                            "format": "int32"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "searchTerm",
                        "in": "path",
                        "required": true,
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "default response",
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "items": {
                                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Kitten"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "security": [
                    {
                        "Auth": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "/v1/tool/category/{hierarchyId}/{categoryId}": {
            "get": {
                "tags": [
                    "V1-tool"
                ],
                "summary": "Get Category data needed to render a Table View in the Category Management tool",
                "operationId": "getTableView",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "hierarchyId",
                        "in": "path",
                        "required": true,
                        "schema": {
                            "minimum": 1,
                            "type": "integer",
                            "format": "int32"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "categoryId",
                        "in": "path",
                        "required": true,
                        "schema": {
                            "minimum": 1,
                            "type": "integer",
                            "format": "int32"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "default response",
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/TableViewResponse"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "security": [
                    {
                        "Auth": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "Kitten": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": [
                            "Kitten"
                        ]
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "format": "int32"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "uri": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "HierarchyResponse": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": [
                            "Hierarchy"
                        ]
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "format": "int32"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "AliasCategoryResponse": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": [
                            "Alias"
                        ]
                    },
                    "level": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "format": "int32"
                    },
                    "uri": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "ChildCategoryResponse": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": [
                            "Category"
                        ]
                    },
                    "level": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "format": "int32"
                    },
                    "uri": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "GblSubheaderResponse": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": [
                            "Translation"
                        ]
                    },
                    "brandCatalogId": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "format": "int32"
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "Item": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "oneOf": [
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ChildCategoryResponse"
                    },
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/AliasCategoryResponse"
                    },
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SubheaderResponse"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "ParentCategoryResponse": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": [
                            "ParentCategory"
                        ]
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "format": "int32"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "SubheaderResponse": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": [
                            "Subheader"
                        ]
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "translatedNames": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/GblSubheaderResponse"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "TableViewResponse": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": [
                            "DefaultCategory"
                        ]
                    },
                    "uri": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "level": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "format": "int32"
                    },
                    "parentCategory": {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ParentCategoryResponse"
                    },
                    "items": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Item"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "securitySchemes": {
            "Auth": {
                "type": "http",
                "description": "Token Authentication  e.g. Bearer <placeholder>",
                "scheme": "bearer",
                "bearerFormat": "JWT"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We run the following command to generate Flow types from the above schema file:

```
npx swagger-to-flowtype path/to/schema/file -d generated_types.js
```

And that results in the following output:

```
// @flow strict
export type Kitten = { type: "Kitten", id: number, name: string, uri: string };
export type HierarchyResponse = { type: "Hierarchy", id: number, name: string };
export type AliasCategoryResponse = {
  type: "Alias",
  level: string,
  name: string,
  id: number,
  uri: string
};
export type ChildCategoryResponse = {
  type: "Category",
  level: string,
  name: string,
  id: number,
  uri: string
};
export type GblSubheaderResponse = {
  type: "Translation",
  brandCatalogId: number,
  value: string
};
export type Item = { type: string };
export type ParentCategoryResponse = {
  type: "ParentCategory",
  id: number,
  name: string
};
export type SubheaderResponse = {
  type: "Subheader",
  name: string,
  translatedNames: Array<GblSubheaderResponse>
};
export type TableViewResponse = {
  type: "DefaultCategory",
  uri: string,
  level: string,
  name: string,
  id: number,
  parentCategory: ParentCategoryResponse,
  items: Array<Item>
};
```

The problem is that the `Item` type is defined as:

```
export type Item = { type: string };
```

And we'd like it to be defined instead as:

```
export type Item = ChildCategoryResponse | AliasCategoryResponse | SubheaderResponse;
```

The relevant part of our OpenAPI schema is:

```
"Item": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "type": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ChildCategoryResponse"
        },
        {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/AliasCategoryResponse"
        },
        {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SubheaderResponse"
        }
    ]
},
```

We we're initially thinking that perhaps `swagger-to-flowtype` had a bug here, but using the same schema to generate TypeScript types via `swagger-typescript-api` outputs something similar:

```
export enum Item {
  Category = "Category",
  Alias = "Alias",
  Subheader = "Subheader",
}
...
export interface TableViewResponse {
  type?: "DefaultCategory";
  uri?: string;
  level?: string;
  name?: string;
  /** @format int32 */
  id?: number;
  parentCategory?: ParentCategoryResponse;
  items?: Item[];
}
```

Notice that in both the Flow and TypeScript types, we should have type information for the shape of each possible object that an `Item` could be, but we do not have any such type information.

Here's a concrete example of an array of items:

```
const items: Array<Item> = [
  {
    type: "Alias",
    level: "3",
    name: "name",
    id: 42,
    uri: "uri"
  },
  {
    type: "Category",
    level: "2",
    name: "name",
    id: 45,
    uri: "uri"
  }
]
```

Hopefully it is now clear why `export type Item = { type: string };` isn't the correct type definition.

Question:

Is there a different schema that would generate the desired `export type Item = ChildCategoryResponse | AliasCategoryResponse | SubheaderResponse` output instead of the current `export type Item = { type: string };` output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understood reading [the OpenAPI specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/d9ac75b00c8bf405c2c90cfa9f20370564371dec/versions/3.1.0.md), `oneOf` and `type` are not supposed to be used together.  It doesn’t seem to have been stated explicitly, but examples in the specification use one or the other, never both.  I assume the TypeScript binding generator, upon seeing that `type` is `"object"`, simply constructs the type based on `properties` and ignores the `oneOf`.

If you want to distinguish the `type` property as disambiguating between the types in the union, you should use [`discriminator`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/d9ac75b00c8bf405c2c90cfa9f20370564371dec/versions/3.1.0.md#discriminator-object) instead of `properties`:

```json
"Item": {
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ChildCategoryResponse"
        },
        {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/AliasCategoryResponse"
        },
        {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SubheaderResponse"
        }
    ],
    "discriminator": {
        "propertyName": "type",
        "mapping": {
            "Category": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ChildCategoryResponse"
            },
            "Alias": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/AliasCategoryResponse"
            },
            "Subheader": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SubheaderResponse"
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: This works perfectly when using `swagger-typescript-api` since `Item` is defined as `export type Item = ChildCategoryResponse | AliasCategoryResponse | SubheaderResponse;` 

Seems like there may be a bug with `swagger-to-flowtype` since `Item` is being defined as `export type Item = {};`. 

Regardless, this answer seems correct to me. Thank you so much!